# How can I search my Exchange logs using Powershell?

Tags: iis, powershell, logging, smtp, exchange-server

This is a preliminary script, it's a bit ugly and needs some work (esp. the pop3 logs section) but I use it periodically to make my life easier.  It's intended to be used in the Powershell ISE so I included the Easy Rerun section at the bottom.  Feel free to offer suggestions, fixes, and cleanup if you find it useful.

Make sure to update the MailServerName and Log Folders to match your environment.

> ```
>     # == Begin by setting these ==
>     $SearchFilter = "sonic.net"
>     $StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) #(Get-Date 10/01/2012)
>     $EndDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-0) #(Get-Date 11/01/2012)
>     $mailserver = "MailServerName"
>     $OutputFolder = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\ExchangeLogs\"
>     $IISLogsFolder = "\\$mailserver\c$\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1"
>     $POP3LogsFolder = "\\$mailserver\c$\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Logging\POP3" # Untested
>     $SMTPLogsFolder = "\\$mailserver\c$\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\MessageTracking"
>     $POP3OutFile = "$OutputFolder\ExchangePOP3Logs.csv"
>     $IISOutFile = "$OutputFolder\ExchangeIISLogs (owa, exchange, and activesync).csv"
>     $SMTPOutFile = "$OutputFolder\ExchangeSMTPLogs.csv"
>
>     # == Initialization ==
>     function Check-IISLogs {
>         $IISFiles = Get-ChildItem $IISLogsFolder *.log|Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -gt $StartDate) -and ($_.CreationTime -lt $EndDate)}
>         $IISHeader = ($IISFiles|Select-Object -First 1|Get-Content|select-string "#fields"|Select-Object -First 1).ToString().Substring(9).split(" ")
>         $IISLogs = $IISFiles|Get-Content|Select-String $SearchFilter # might be able to do RegEx search (untested)
>         $IISLogsCsv = $IISLogs|ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter " " -header $IISHeader
>         $IISLogsCSV|Export-Csv -Path "$IISOutFile"
>         #start excel "$IISOutFile"
>     }
>
>     function Check-Pop3Logs {  # !!!UNTESTED!!!
>         $POP3Files = Get-ChildItem $POP3LogsFolder *.log|Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -gt $StartDate) -and ($_.CreationTime -lt $EndDate)}
>         $POP3Header = ($POP3Files|Select-Object -First 1|Get-Content|select-string "#fields"|Select-Object -First 1).ToString().Substring(9).split(" ") #ToDo: update select-string, substring, and split([delimiter])
>         $POP3Logs = $POP3Files|Get-Content|Select-String $SearchFilter # might be able to do RegEx search (untested)
>         $POP3LogsCsv = $POP3Logs|ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter " " -header $POP3Header #ToDo: update Delimiter
>         $POP3LogsCSV|Export-Csv -Path "$POP3OutFile"
>         #start excel "$POP3OutFile"
>     }
>
>     function Check-SMTPLogs {
>         $SMTPFiles = Get-ChildItem $SMTPLogsFolder *.log|Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -gt $StartDate) -and ($_.CreationTime -lt $EndDate)}
>         $SMTPHeader = ($SMTPFiles|Select-Object -First 1|Get-Content|select-string "#fields"|Select-Object -First 1).ToString().Substring(9).split(",")
>         $SMTPLogs = $SMTPFiles|Get-Content|Select-String $SearchFilter # might be able to do RegEx search (untested
>         $SMTPLogsCsv = $SMTPLogs|ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "," -header $SMTPHeader
>         $SMTPLogsCSV|Export-Csv -Path "$SMTPOutFile"
>         #start excel "$SMTPOutFile"
>     }
>
>
>     # == Run ==
>
>     Check-IISLogs
>     #Check-Pop3Logs # doesn't work yet
>     Check-SMTPLogs
>     New-Item -Type Directory $OutputFolder -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
>
>     start $OutputFolder
>
>
>     <# -- Easy rerun
>     $SearchFilter = "username"
>     #$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) #(Get-Date 10/01/2012)
>     #$EndDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-0) #(Get-Date 11/01/2012)
>     Check-IISLogs
>     #Check-Pop3Logs # doesn't work yet
>     Check-SMTPLogs
>     start $OutputFolder
>     #>
> ```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question was "How can I search my Exchange logs using Powershell?"  I posted this for someone on a spiceworks forum, and I figured it made sense to post it here so that other people can use it as a starting point if they have similar needs

Comment: Oh. The post at the top of the page should be a question. That's the format: a question at the top, and then people present their answers below. You can answer your own question if you like.